# Profit/Loss from Income and Expenditure Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables for Income and Exenditure, each having date and currency fields. Income: IncomeDate, AmountPaid; Expenditure: ExpenseDate, TotalAmount. I want write an SQL query to subtract expenditure from income to get a profit/loss field on distict dates found in the two tables.
I have tried:

```sql
SELECT 
  Income.IncomeDate, 
  SUM(AmountPaid) AS DailyIncome, 
  Expenditure.ExpenseDate, 
  SUM(TotalAmount) AS DailyExpenditure 
FROM Income
  FULL OUTER JOIN Expenditure ON IncomeDate=ExpenditureDate
GROUP BY IncomeDate 
ORDER BY IncomeDate
```

... but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is because when you join on the date, you are essentially duplicating the number of records you have.  So you really have 2 options here.

1. Divide the aggregate sum by the factor of aggregates you're pulling in.  This is a dirty solution, but it works.

```sql
select i.incomedate, sum(i.amountpaid) /2 as dailyincome, sum(e.totalamount) /2 as dailyexpenditure
from income i 
join expense e on e.expensedate= i.incomedate
group by e.expensedate, i.incomedate
```

2. The better way to do this would be to execute these queries separately through cte and then mash them together in a result set.  It's probably overengineering but it's less kludgey than dividing the results by 2.  It should also be way more performant than a join.

My format might be wrong, I don't have access to SQL directly in front of me, but this is the general flow.

```sql
with inc as (
select incomedate as idate, sum(amountpaid) as dailyincome
from income
group by amountpaid
),

exp as (
select expensedate as edate, sum(totalamount) as dailyexpenditure
from expenditure
)

select idate, dailyincome, dailyexpenditure
from inc join exp on edate = idate
```